# React does not recognize the `enterKeyHint` prop on a DOM element

Tags: react-native, styled-components

A react-native app implementing Styled Components and Scroll view is working, but gives me this warning:

```
index.js:1 Warning: React does not recognize the `enterKeyHint` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `enterkeyhint` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.
    in input (created by TextInput)
    in TextInput (created by Context.Consumer)
    in StyledNativeComponent (created by Styled(TextInput))
    in Styled(TextInput) (at Signup.js:96)
    in div (created by View)
    in View (created by ScrollView)
    in div (created by View)
    in View (created by ForwardRef)
    in ForwardRef (created by ScrollView)
    in ScrollView (at Signup.js:95)
```

This is the component's render:

```
 return (
        <BasicView>
            {isLoading && <Preloader/>}
            <ScrollView>
      LOC 96 -> <BasicInput placeholder="email" value={email} onChangeText={(val) => setEmail(val)}/>
                <BasicInput placeholder="password" value={password} onChangeText={(val) => setPassword(val)}
                            maxLength={15} secureTextEntry={true}/>
                <BasicInput placeholder="name" value={displayName} onChangeText={(val) => setDisplayName(val)}/>
                <Button title="Signup" onPress={() => registerUser()}/>
                <BasicLink onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate(NavigationLocations.LOGIN)}>
                    Already registered? Click here to log in...
                </BasicLink>
            </ScrollView>
        </BasicView>
    )
```

And here is the styled component's definition:

```
export const BasicInput = styled.TextInput`
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;  
    align-self: center;
    border-color: #ccc;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
`;
```

What does the `enterKeyHint` refer to? What correction should I implement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue comes from React Native Web.
Not sure in which version this appears.
Anyway, I went back to version 0.12.3 and I don't get this warning anymore.

enterKeyHint is an html property used for Virtual keyboards. It is a way to rename the [ENTER] key.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/enterKeyHint

The warning doesn't appears on Andoid or iOS. So you can safely ignore this warning if you are not willing to downgrade your React Native Web version as you are most likely do not need to rename [ENTER] key on Virtual keyboard on web.

Comment: Would you know about a way to disable that warning?

Comment: Besides downgrading, no.

Comment: What about today ? was this issue not fixed by rnw ?

Comment: version 0.13.12 works as well. `npm install --save react-native-web@0.13.12`

Comment: If you look at the error stack trace, it may be a hint as to where it comes from. I had to go through and start upgrading all of my packages. Eventually the error went away. Wish I could say which package is was, but I have no idea. I know that's not helpful, but if anyone is banging their head against the wall, get `Version Lens` in VSCode and upgrade the react related packages.